# Need few references of ArcGIS Java Script API version 2.8

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need few samples from version 2.8 & I have check the site but Esri hosted latest version 3.2 so where should I get version 2.8 ??

I gone through [this](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/59939-Can-you-still-get-to-a-2.8-javascript-help-site-!) post regarding 2.8 version..and the only way is that I need to download SDK and install it on my machine..but is there any live link available for version 2.8??

Comment: That forum post is right. Only the latest sdk help is available online. The SDK download isn't that big. It seems like a reasonable option.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe thanks for your reply..Please mark this as answer..thanks : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That forum post is right. Only the latest sdk help is available online. The SDK download isn't that big. I would suggest that you download it and use that.